# Aspose.Word Pdf properties

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I create Pdа via Aspose.Word
Can't find any class for modify pdf propeties to set author of document

Тип Время   Сообщение
22:24:44    Компиляция кода проекта Ошибка при компиляции общего кода "CS0246" "The type or namespace name 'PdfSaveOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". [Строка: 120; Cтолбец: 4]

Something like:

```
PdfSaveOptions options = new PdfSaveOptions();
options.ExportGeneratorName = false;
doc.Save(output, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set these properties using [Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.properties/builtindocumentproperties)